# simple_form - how to specify form's action attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, action, edit, simple-form

I am using simple_form gem and have a ordinary rails scaffold which is working perfectly - I am able to update/create/destroy records.

When I add the views in application  *<%= yield %>* a issue occurred - the simple_form gem is rendering a form with action "/" for the new action and I was not able to create new records.

In my controller, the path for create action is

```
 #POST /webinars
```

So, I edit the action of the form from "/" to "/webinars" (using the browser console) and then successfully create a record.

I suppose that I should override the action of the from somehow, but was not able to find how.
Is this the real problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: '/webinars' do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am passing the url value as partial parameter and it is working great. When the parameter is not passed the url option is populated with its default value. Could you tell if this is standard simple_form behaviour?

Comment: what do you mean default value?

Comment: If I do not specify URL attribute, for "Edit" action the generated URL is "/webinars/32" for example. So, simple_form gem do everything perfectly for "edit" action, but not for "new" action. Now, I am passing @url variable as partial parameter. For 'new' action I am passing '/webinars', but for 'edit' I am passing nothing and the gem generated the right url alone.

Comment: well, it's how `form_for` helper works. It uses [url_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/url_for) method under the hood to generate action. You can check doc on `url_for` to know more about it.